# Geometry Nodes: Get the neighboring vertices of endpoint vertices

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am using Vertex Count: Vertex Neighbors to generate a selection based on the endpoints of a series of mesh lines, then do something with that selection. My problem: how do I ALSO get the NEXT vertex? Or to put it another way, how do I convert that selection to edges that include said vertices?

In the image below, I have circled in blue the verts that I would like to include for the Set Position node. The sphere/instance on point is just for visualization. The use-case for this will include edges of arbitrary start and end positions, vertex counts, and distances between vertices, so it need to affect the circled vertices by index, not by position or proximity to the endpoint verts.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

GN Curves offer you a very convenient *Endpoint Selection*, for this case, with a variable range. So you can convert to a curve, capture the selection, and convert back to a mesh.

[image]

You can make use of the selection as edges, further down the tree:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, a perfect little answer! I knew it was going to be something ridiculously simple I was missing just in my periphery.