# Trying to get neighboring vertices

Tags: geometry-nodes

Here is my current approach. I am probably misusing the "Edges of vertex" node.
Anyway I don't really know how to solve this problem.
My current solution works if the vertex Id is a constant number that has been inputted by the user, but for my use I need it to be able to use an id that has been acquired by any mean that is similar to the approach I chosen or really any approach.
Yes I am aware I could skip the first few nodes and just plug the vertex Id in, but that wouldn't be actually usable for anything beyond that.

From my observations it doesn't work, because the vertex id(vertex in the repeat zone) is using the index node and when used in the selection it basically only works for the vertex id (64), I was trying to find a way around it, but I was unsuccessful.

If there is a way to get neighboring vertices then I will appreciate it if you would be so kind to share this method.
Thanks for reading all of this, I am not good at explaining stuff.
[image]

Comment: Does this help
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/269127/geometry-nodes-get-the-neighboring-vertices-of-endpoint-vertices

Comment: Can you say how you want to _use_  your neighbouring vertices? That would clarify the overall problem a lot.

Comment: what are you trying to get? the index of the neighbors? if so you are not outputs any index, you are just keeping the vertex index and and iteration ID. you are storing a boolean temp value; What is what? what are you checking for and what are you trying to get?

Comment: your setup doesn’t really maks sense (at least for what your question is)